# Performance of ListView in React Native + Redux application

Tags: listview, react-native, redux

I have a [`ListView`](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/listview.html), which, obviously, renders list of some items. Before, I was using React Native without Redux, so when my underlying data changes, I was calling `setState()`, modifying the data, then `dataSource = dataSource.cloneWithRows(itemsData);`, and it was quite performant: each row was re-rendered if only its data changes (i.e. if my `rowHasChanged()` returned `true` for that row).

But, the overall application design was quite ad-hoc and not very well maintainable, so I decided to try Redux.

Now, my scene is "pure", that is, it depends solely on the passed props, which are generated by means of `mapStateToProps()`. But the problem is that whenever any item changes, the whole `ListView` element is recreated, therefore, all items are re-rendered (my `rowHasChanged()` is not even called). This is quite frustrating, since the only way to get rid of this behaviour is to make the scene non-pure again: add the state, and somehow update it when needed.

Or, what are other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent unnecessary re-render by making your own check in [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate). Also, to speed up comparison by making a shallow compare only, try making your data immutable with a library like [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js).

Here is an example using ListView.DataSource and an immutable dataset taken from [this article](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/react-native-immutable-listview-example-78662fa64a15):

```
// Use immutable.is() to achieve efficient change detection.
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
    rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => !immutable.is(r1, r2)
})
// Shallow convert to a JS array, leaving immutable row data.
this.state = {
    dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(countries.toArray())
}
```

In `redux`, when connecting your component, make sure to use `mapStateToProps()` to filter your data. By using this technique, and passing the relevant props only, you probably won't even have to use `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: @Dmitry Frank Did that answer helped you?